# jQuery send multidimensional input ajax

Tags: ajax, forms

I have the following html structure.

```
<form id="inner" name="dummy">
    ...
        <input type="text" name="set[0][0][xy]" />
        <input type="text" name="set[0][1]" />
        <input type="text" name="set[1][axy]" />
        <input type="text" name="set[2][asxy]" />
        <input type="text" name="set[2][1][xdsay]" />
        <input type="text" name="set[2][2][xasdy]" />
    ...
</form>
```

I need to send the fields only with `name="set[....]"` by ajax. And the depth of the multidimensional array is changing.

Any idea?

Comment: And yes, I am not able to change the structure.

Comment: So you want to send all the fields? your description is very vague. Also I see an `ajax` tag but no ajax code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all your markup is invalid you can't have a form in another form, the browser's parser will sort that out.
Your problem is that you selector is wrong, there if no form with name `inner`, the form has an id `inner`, so your selector will be `form[id="inner"]` or `form#inner` or `#inner`

Comment: Ok. Do you have any solution? I need the fields, with name "set" to be send.

Comment: @user1279563 I gave you the selector to use to select the form, just serialize it and you have the fields.

Comment: Ok, my bad I realize that I wrote name above.